# Catch keypress of special characters with android

Tags: android, keyboard

how can I catch a keypress of all characters that are on sw keyboards?
Overriding onKeyDown() in the activity works only for standard ASCII characters like a-z0-9-!/... but doesn't work with all the UTF8 chars like ščřž (in that case this method is not called at all)
I know the KeyEvent has a method getUnicodeChar(), which returns the unicode character that the key would produce. But I dont know how to get that KeyEvent when onKeyDown() is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried it but there is a method called dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event). I hope it will surely meet ur needs.

Comment: THX it works, now I need to figure out, how to get UTF8 code of that special characters, because  keyEvent.getUnicodeChar() returns 0 for them

Comment: u can use event.getKeycode() to get the keycode and use it as you want.............