# Catching special key events in android

Tags: java, android, special-characters, onkeydown

I have a onKeyDown event that can catch all the regular character events, like "a", "b", "c" and so on. But I can't figure out how to register special characters like "æ", "ø" and "å" from the Danish language. I have tried writing some code that logs the KeyCode when I press those special characters but it would seem like that just returns a 0.

I have searched this site quite a bit and I found this:
[Catch keypress of special characters with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462045/catch-keypress-of-special-characters-with-android)

But I am unsure if that can help me and how I should use it, if it is the way to go.

Comment: What is your keylistener doing with selected characters?

Comment: It basically just takes the key pressed, say I pressed 'a', and puts it into a string variable. I then get a byte array from that string and send it with UDP.

Comment: Wouldn't an EditText field work the same way and potentially easier?

Comment: The user isn't supposed to see what they're typing on the screen. But how would that help me?

Comment: I was looking into the problem and happened across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967740/onkeylistener-not-working-with-soft-keyboard-android which says that softkeyboards from 1.6 up doesn't seem to like onkeylistener and would rather you implement textwatcher.

Comment: I just saw I wrote something incorrect in the text. I meant an onKeyDown event, not a KeyListener, sorry!